# Laravel Task Scheduling Every X Hours

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, laravel-5.4

I undestand that you can create hourly tasks on Laravel by using:

`$schedule->command('catalog:update')->hourly();`

however is there a way to do for example every 2 hours or 5 hours? I couldn't find it on documentation or here.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You've tagged your question as Laravel 4, but I don't think the scheduler was introduced until Laravel 5...

Anyway, based on the code snippet you've posted, you could use the `cron` method.

```
$schedule->command('catalog:update')->cron('0 */2 * * *'); // every 2 hours
$schedule->command('catalog:update')->cron('0 */5 * * *'); // every 5 hours
```

See the docs for other options. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling#defining-schedules

Comment: I just fixed the tag. sorry about that. Is that for Laravel 5? So in crobtab `* * * * * php /path/to//artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` again?

Comment: Thanks a lot... :)

Answer (score 2):

From Laravel 7 By Defalut you can give like this

```
$schedule->command('catalog:update')->everyTwoHours();
$schedule->command('catalog:update')->everyFiveHours();
```

See Docs:https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling

Answer (score 0):

Laravel scheduling hours cron-command can only run a task every 2 hours, 3 hours, 4 hours and 6 hours.There is no everyFiveHours() command you will have to use the `cron` command for 5 hours, `cron('0 */5 * * *')`.

Below commands are supported:

```
->everyTwoHours();  
->everyThreeHours();    
->everyFourHours(); 
->everySixHours();
```